# ChartJs/React how to update state of nested object within a nested object

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the state (using API data) of a nested object that is nested within another object but I can't seem to get it working. It keeps telling me that 'datasets' is undefined.

```
 this.state = {
     chartData:{
       datasets: [
        {
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        dataToUpdate: []
        }
       ]
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=30&page=1&sparkline=true')
            .then(res => {
                const APIdata = res.data[0];

                this.setState({
                   data: {
                       ...this.state.data,
                       datasets: [{
                        ...this.state.data.datasets[0],
                        dataToUpdate: APIdata,
                       }]
                   }
                })
                console.log(this.state.chartData.datasets[0].dataToUpdate);
            })
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to update objects in datasets variable?

Comment: Yeah, just to update the dataToUpdate array variable with the values from the api..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update objects in datasets variable like this

```
const { chartData } = this.state;
chartData.datasets.map((set) => {
  set.fill = true;
});
this.setState({
  chartData: chartData,
});
```